# How to get the servername\hostname in Firebird 2.5.x

Tags: firebird

I use Firebird 2.5, and I want to retrieve the following values

Username:
I used `SELECT rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'CURRENT_USER') FROM ...`

Database name:
I used `SELECT rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'DB_NAME') FROM ...`

But for server name, I did not find any client API, do you know how can I retrieve the server name with a SELECT statement.

Comment: Why do you need this? A client already needs to know the hostname to be able to connect. In addition, a server can have multiple hostnames, al which could be used depending on the bind-address. The only option is to obtain the full version string through the database-info API, as that will contain the hostname of the server and client components.

Comment: I need this because we have many data sources and different environments so we use these three values for auditing. Could you please tell me more information about the only option "database info API"?

Comment: You can retrieve version information for each 'hop' connecting to Firebird (client side info, server y-valve, and db engine), although exact contents varies by client and connection type. This is accessed through the database info API, which in the low-level native API is accessed through the `isc_database_info` function and the `isc_info_firebird_version` information item. However it might be simpler (because accessible through SQL), to for example use an external table with the environment information, or maybe use an UDR or UDF to obtain the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in in Firebird to obtain the server host name (or host names, as a server can have multiple host names) through SQL.

The closest you can get is by requesting the `isc_info_firebird_version` information item through the `isc_database_info` API function. This returns version information that - if connecting through TCP/IP - includes a host name of the server.

But as your primary reason for this is to discern between environments in SQL, it might be better to look for a different solution. Some ideas:

## Use an external table

You can create an [external table](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-external) to contain the environment information you need.

In this example I just put in a short, fixed width name for the environment types, but you could include other information. However, be aware the external table format is a binary format. When using `CHAR` it will look like a fixed width text format, where values shorter than declared need to be padded with spaces.

You can follow these steps:

1. Configure `ExternalFileAccess` in `firebird.conf` (for this example, you'd need to set `ExternalFileAccess = Restrict D:\data\DB\exttables`).
2. You can then create a table as

   ```sql
   create table environment 
     external file 'D:\data\DB\exttables\environment.dat' (
     environment_type CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL 
   )
   ```
3. Next, create the file `D:\data\DB\exttables\environment.dat` and populate it with exactly three characters (e.g. `TST` for test, `PRO` for production, etc). You can also insert the value instead, the external table file will be created automatically. Inserting might be simpler if you want more columns, or data with varying length, etc. Just keep in mind it is binary, but using `CHAR` for all columns will make it look like text.

Do this for each environment, and make sure the file is read-only to avoid accidental inserts.

After this is done, you can obtain the environment information using

```sql
select environment_type 
from environment
```

You can share the same file for multiple databases on the same host, and external files are - by default - not included in a gbak backup (they are only included if you apply the `-convert` backup option), so this would allow moving database between environments without dragging this information along.

## Use an UDF or UDR

You can write an UDF (User-Defined Function) or UDR (User Defined Routine) in a suitable programming language to return the information you want and define this function in your database. Firebird can then call this function from SQL.

UDFs are considered deprecated, and you should use UDRs - introduced in Firebird 3 - instead if possible.

I have never written an UDF or UDR myself, so I can't describe it in detail.